# parse KML in Google Web Toolkit

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, kml

I have a kml file which I want to present on a map. I'm using Google Maps v3 for GWT. However, I've read that the kml file should be on a public server.I've searched for methods that can use local kml files, but all of them regard Javascript, not java.

Is there a way to use local KML files in Google Web Toolkit? 
Should I use an XML parser instead and then try to work on the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to present my kml file on my map, usinh geoxml3 JS. I call JS functions from my GWT project and I use JS to present my kml on the map. However, I still haven't find a way to remove the layers from my map...!

Comment: Can you please explain hoe exactly didi you do it?